# Vue Socket.io Not Receiving Data

Tags: node.js, sockets, vue.js, vuex, flask-socketio

I currently have a Python Flask SocketIO application that will be connecting to a Vue app using [this socket.io library](https://github.com/MetinSeylan/Vue-Socket.io). The Vue app (currently) will poll the Python application using socket.io on a button press. I can correctly receive the data sent from Vue; however, Vue is not receiving the data. Currently, my actions/mutations looks like this:

```
const actions = {
  fbCommentsPerPost: (context) => {
    console.log('fb comments per post sent!')
    socket.emit('fb comments per post', { post_id: '123' })
    // socket.on('data', function (resp) {
    //   console.log(resp)
    // })
  },
  socket_connectResp: (context, message) => {
    console.log(message)
  },
  socket_fbData: (context, message) => {
    console.log(message)
  }
}

// mutations
const mutations = {
  SOCKET_FB_DATA: (state, status) => {
    console.log('comments!!!!')
  }
}
```

Using the README for this project, the `socket_fbData` *should* be receiving the data from the Python app (the backend is emitting 'fb data'). When I run a simple client in node using `socket.io-client`, this works and I can properly receive data. Moreover, when I uncomment the socket.on block in `fbCommentsPerPost`, I can at least console log the data. Is there something I'm missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`vue-socket.io` has an issue with converting socket events to actions and mutations. It kind of works but not as expected. Check issue [#117](https://github.com/MetinSeylan/Vue-Socket.io/issues/117)

A few months ago there was few PRs with a fix for this issue but some [edge cases](https://github.com/MetinSeylan/Vue-Socket.io/pull/118) are not covered. So you can **try the latest version** or just **move to [`vue-socket.io-extended`](https://github.com/probil/vue-socket.io-extended)** instead.